# How to adjust axes labels, title position, and font sizes of scatter plot created using plotly graph_objects?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm creating a 3d scatter plot using plotly.graph_objects, and I'm trying to customize my axes labels and to center the plot title. In this example, my plot consists of a helix, together with a single point at the origin:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# Helix equation
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
x, y, z = np.cos(t), np.sin(t), t

fig = go.Figure()

# Add ellipse to figure
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x, 
y=y,z=z,mode='markers',marker_color='red',marker_size=5,name='Helix'))

# Add origin to figure
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[0], y=[0],z= 
[0],mode='markers',marker_color='blue',marker_size=10,name='Origin'))

fig.update_layout(title="Helix")
fig.show()
```

The graph appears as below.

[image]

I'm struggling to modify this so as to do the following:

1. Center the title.
2. Relabel the axes. I tried relabelling the x-axis using

   ```
     fig.update_xaxes(title='New x label')
   ```

but this had no effect.

3. Adjust the font sizes of the title and axes separately. Adjusting the layout using

   ```
     fig.update_layout(title="Helix",font_size=16)
   ```

not surprisingly adjusted the font size of both my title and my axes labels.

Comment: Try looking at [Setting the Font, Title, Legend Entries, Label, and Axis Titles in Python](https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/) and [how to change the title font size in Plotly Code Example](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+change+title+font+size+in+plotly).

Comment: @Alias Cartellano: Thanks for the tip. So, I to center the title and adjust its fontsize,:

        `fig.update_layout(title_text='Helix', title_x=0.5)`

        `fig['layout']['title']['font'] = dict(size=22)`

Changing the axes labels is where I'm stuck. The `update_layout` method at 
https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.html#plotly.basedatatypes.BaseFigure.update_layout

is leaving me a bit confused insofar as what I use for my properties in the `dict` argument.

Comment: Use `fig.update_layout(
    title="Helix",
    scene = dict(
                    xaxis_title='X AXIS TITLE',
                    yaxis_title='Y AXIS TITLE',
                    zaxis_title='Z AXIS TITLE'),
                    width=700,
                    margin=dict(r=20, b=10, l=10, t=10)
)` to update the axis. The `scene` parameter is what affects axis on 3d graphs.

Comment: Works great. If you'd enter this as a solution, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted. Thanks so much.